# python decorator arguments

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

Do python decorator function support arguments a how is the implementation

```
def decorator(fn, decorArg):
    print "I'm decorating!"
    print decorArg
    return fn

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    @decorator
    def my_function(self, funcArg = None):
        print "Hi"
        print funcArg
```

on run I got this error

```
TypeError: decorator() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I've tried @decorator(arg) or @ decorator arg . it did not work as well. So far I wonder if this is possible

Comment: Yes, but your example seems to indicate that you don't understand how decorators work.  Have you read, for instance, [this](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#current-syntax)?  What do you want your decorator to do?

Comment: You should read this post order to better understand how to use decorators: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators

Answer (score 3):

I think you might want something like this:

```
class decorator:
    def __init__ (self, decorArg):
        self.arg = decorArg

    def __call__ (self, fn):
        print "I'm decoratin!"
        print self.arg
        return fn

class MyClass (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.list = []

    @decorator ("foo")
    def my_function (self, funcArg = None):
        print "Hi"
        print funcArg

MyClass ().my_function ("bar")
```

Or with nested functions as BlackNight pointed out:

```
def decorator (decorArg):
    def f (fn):
        print "I'm decoratin!"
        print decorArg
        return fn
    return f
```

Comment: You can also do it with nested functions, rather than a decorator class. Alas, Python's indentation requirements don't let me type an example here in the comments.